# Defining a shortcut for \end{frame} gives an error in beamer

Tags: beamer, macros

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\def\efr{\end{frame}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Test
\efr
% \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Why this document fails

```
$ pdflatex main.tex
Runaway argument?
\let \AtEndDocument \@firstofone \@enddocumenthook \@checkend {docume\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \beamer@collect@@body.
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

I want to define shortcuts `\bfr` and `\efr` for a frame.

Comment: This is not the best idea, sorry! `beamer` frames using verbatim mode, your definition leads to a state where `\end{frame}` is never seen. Don't do it, there's no real gain of it !

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way around it?

Comment: @slitvinov The best way around it is to use `\end{frame}`.

Comment: @slitvinov: As I said: You won't gain anything by sparing some characters to type. As samcarter wrote: Just use `\end{frame}` and you will save your life ;-)

Comment: @slitvinov If you think typing `\begin{frame} \end{frame}` costs you too much time, rather look into a good tex editor, which provides shortcuts or auto-complete.

Comment: You could do `\long\def\bfr#1\efr{\begin{frame}#1\end{frame}}` but then forget about several `beamer` features. As others have already pointed out, where's the advantage in obscuring the markup?

Comment: @samcarter Thank you for you suggestion. But I think you are not considering that the text is often read after typing.

Comment: @samcarter: You have the beamer gold hammer badge, haven't you?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for helping out with your `macro`-hammer :) I first vtc with another duplicate, but I think this ones fits better - and apparently the gold hammer only works once.

Comment: @samcarter: I thought it can be used multiple times...

Comment: @samcarter Thank you. The duplicate you suggested answers my question completely.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have experimental proof that it does not work more than once.

Comment: @samcarter: Ok, I'll believe ... this time ;-)

Comment: @slitvinov No need, everything is fine. Your question simply was marked as a duplicate of the other. So if someone else will search for this and find your question, he/she can follow the link and find the answers.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer A theoretician is believing the experimentalist? Something to remember!

Comment: @samcarter: While theoreticians are always right (cough!!!!), it is necessary to acknowledge that experimentialists could be right once a while too ;-)